# How to get transaction command text from SQL server Log file

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log

I got a list of the `transaction` from `fn_dblog` and would like to get the command text of the specific transaction by [Transaction Id]. Would you please guide me about that

Answer (score 1):

This isn't logged anywhere (by default). You can investigate the "server audit" functionality and see if that gives you what you want.